# Не получается отправить запросы на бекенд после перехода на https

Tags: apache, http, flask, https, axios

Есть сайт на react. Загрузил его на сервер, установил его на сервер. Поставил ssl certificate. Все страницы работают нормально, загружаются, но запросы с форм перестали доходить до бекенда. Раньше пользовался запросами такого вида:

```
axios.post('http://<server-ip>:80/feedback', data)
```

Сменил на

```
axios.post('https://www.<domain>.com/feedback', data)
```

С такими запросами тоже получаю статус 200 в браузере, но в качестве ответа возвращается:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo_nobg.png"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
        <title>React App</title>
        <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.d5c0a7d3.js"></script>
        <link href="/static/css/main.7ecc86dc.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

И в логах бекенда нет информации об отправленном письме. То есть, как я понял, до моего бекенда дело не доходит. Сам бекенд формы:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

logging.basicConfig(filename='feedback.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

smtp_host = config['smtp_host']
smtp_port = config['smtp_port']
smtp_username = config['smtp_username']
smtp_password = config['smtp_password']
to_address = config['to_address']

@app.route('/feedback/', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def receive_feedback():

    data = request.json
    logging.info(f'Received feedback data: {data}')
    firstname = data['firstname']
    lastname = data['lastname']
    email = data['email']
    subject = data['subject']
    message = data['message']

    
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(f"First Name: {firstname}\nLast Name: {lastname}\nEmail: {email}\nMessage: {message}")

    msg['Subject'] = f"{subject}"
    msg['From'] = smtp_username
    msg['To'] = to_address
    msg['Replay to'] = email

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port) as smtp:
            
            smtp.ehlo()
            context = ssl.create_default_context()
            smtp.starttls(context=context)
            smtp.ehlo()
            smtp.login(user=smtp_username, password=smtp_password)


            smtp.send_message(msg)
        logging.info(f'Sent feedback email to {msg["To"]}')
        return "Thank you for your feedback!"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Failed to send feedback email: {e}')
        return "An error occurred while sending your feedback."
```

apache httpd.conf:

```
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/build"
    ServerName 123cluster.com
    ServerAlias www.123cluster.com
    
    <Directory "/var/www/build">
        RewriteEngine On 
          RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://<domain>.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
          Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
        Require all granted
        # Any other directives
    </Directory>
    # Other directives here
   

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/build"
    ServerName <domain>.com
    ServerAlias www.<domain>.com
    <Directory "/var/www/build">
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
        Require all granted
        # Any other directives
    </Directory>
    # Other directives here
   
    SSLEngine on

    #cert path.
    SSLCertificateFile      <cert-path>
    #key path
    SSLCertificateKeyFile <key-path>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

Что донастроить, чтобы можно было доставить запросы на бекенд?